# jenkins gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed

Tags: jenkins, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install jenkins on Ubuntu14.04 following this [site](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#debianubuntu).

After executing the last step, the terminal shows this error:

```sh
Err https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/ binary/ jenkins 2.235.5
  gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed
E: Failed to fetch https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/binary/jenkins_2.235.5_all.deb  gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried to run `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing` (no errow shown after running this cmd) but it doesn't help.

I also tried to install by downloading `jenkins.war` but the jenkins service isn't enabled after installing.

Please show me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue seems to be upstream (I have hit the same snag this morning trying to update one of my jenkins installls).

You could use wget and dpkg to fetch and install the deb package:

```
wget https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/binary/jenkins_2.235.5_all.deb && sudo dpkg -i jenkins_2.235.5_all.deb
```

Which will get you Jenkins installed.

Comment: This answer saved my life. Anw, what do you mean by saying _The issue seems to be **upstream**_. I just want to understand the reason staying behind this issue. Thank you.

Comment: The root cause appears to be that the upstream repo hosting the deb files has changed it's TLS policy to require TLS1.2. but the trusty host can't negotiate a shared cipher using TLS1.2 with the upstream repo so the apt command fails

Comment: I'm getting the same problem with the lastest update (2.249.1).  Using the above answer fixes the problem...  But are we doomed to update jenkins this way henceforth?   This seems to have started happening after gpg key was changed on April 16th 2020.